# The relation between reduces and storage function in Pig

Tags: machine-learning, apache-pig

I just read this [paper](https://files.ifi.uzh.ch/dbtg/sdbs13/T15.0.pdf) about large scale machine lerning in twitter.

In the paper they noted a figure that show that each reduce has it own storage function (It found in the paper page 5-figure1)

and also noted this code (I made it shorter but pretty the same):

```
training = load `/tables/statuses/$DATE' using TweetLoader() as (id: long, uid: long, text: chararray);
training = foreach training generate $0 as label, $1 as text, RANDOM() as random;
training = order training by random parallel $PARTITIONS;
training = foreach training generate label, text;
store training into `$OUTPUT' using TextLRClassifierBuilder();
```

In my understood, the `parallel $PARTITIONS` triggered pig to create two reducers, but I didn't understand what is the relation to the storage function.
If I set `$PARTITIONS` to be 2, what will be the name of each stored model?
let say that I want the each store function will get 50% of training. How can I do it?
Does all the training available in the memory? There is a way that reduce will get 50% of the training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, `PARALLEL` controls the number of reducers.  And in the Hadoop framework, each reducer produces its own output file. (More than one output file in the case of `MultipleOutputs`.)

Each output file usually has a name like `part-r-00000`, or `part-r-00372`, where the number indicates which reducer produced it. If you have have 100 reducers, you will end up with files `part-r-00000`, `part-r-00001`, ..., `part-r-00099`.

Comment: if my traning is let say 5,8,9,7,4,3. and I juset order in parrallel 2, I will can 2 files like this 3,4,5 and 7,8,9 or 5,8,9 and 3,4,7. I mean Each file will be sorted only or also all the numbers in file 1 will be smaller then the numbers in file2? (should I open a new qustion for that?)

Comment: Read up on Hadoop's shuffle and sort phases.

Comment: I read about it over here http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#dataflow in my understand the suffle process couse the result to be like like this 3,4,5 and 7,8,9. Am I right?